# Flickering white lines

Tags: display, bug, ui

I have a Mac Pro (Late 2013, OS X 10.13.1) and a 4k monitor from Sharp that was back then sold as the standard display. I'm using a scaled resolution on the monitor since otherwise, the font would be too small. Since an earlier update of OSX, I'm experiencing small white lines that sometimes flicker across the screen.

This issue seems to be related to the following Apple Community questions:

- [Flickering Screen with macOs 10.12.4](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7910215?start=0&tstart=0)
- [horizontal flickering lines MBP late 2015](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7927273?start=0&tstart=0)
- [white flashing lines on screen macos 10.12.4](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7905583?start=0&tstart=0)
- [Why are there white lines running across my Macbook Pro(late 2013) screen?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7424825?start=0&tstart=0)
- [Horizontal flickering line across the screen](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7144011?start=0&tstart=0)

Most of the answers there are not helpful. I'm very sure that it is not a hardware problem because the flickering stops as soon as I use the native resolution for the monitor. I tried resetting the NVRAM without success. My investigation led to the following findings:

- This issue appears only when I use a scaled resolution. As far as I can tell, it doesn't matter which one
- It *seems* to be connected to media content like web-pages or video. Although I'm not sure, I believe when browsing after a restart there is a certain time point when the flickering starts. After that, it the lines appear even when you only type or move the mouse
- The monitor is connected to a Thunderbolt port. That might be related because some of the above posts mention that they have the issue with external displays.

Has someone any clue what I could try except waiting for a fix?

Comment: Could this possibly be an issue with the screen rather than the Mac? I would try testing with another computer with the same settings to see if it is the computer.

Comment: @JBWar I really doubt that. (a) it worked in the past without any issue (b) it works with native resolution (c) there are a lot of people experiencing the same issue.